# How to skip ExpressGate loading

Tags: bios, asus-laptop, express-gate

I have to install a windows on a laptop which has preinstalled Asus Express Gate on it. The problem is that I am not able to enter the boot settings, so the system would be installed form a flash drive. Is there any way to skip Express Gate loading ?

Note:
The laptop is Asus 1015PX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Shutdown ExpressGate in your BIOS.

Comment: the problem is that I am not seeing a way to enter bios - I've got black screen for approximately 5 seconds, and then Express Gate is loaded

Comment: ok - entered BIOS - where can I disable the Express Gate load ?

Comment: I dont recall exactly, but I think it's in the Advanced section.